# How to implement KStream-Ktable leftJoin, how to get and set the field by using Envelope object and implement the join for KStream-Ktable?

Tags: apache-kafka, left-join, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-join

If I have one topic schema (that is Kstream):

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Value",
    "namespace": "test1",
    "fields": [
          {
              "name": "id",
              "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "connect.default": 0
              },
              "default": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "createdAt",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "connect.version": 1,
                    "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.ZonedTimestamp"
                }
            ],
            "default": null
          }
    ],
    "connect.name": "test1.Value"
}
```

Schema for other topic

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Envelope",
  "namespace": "test2",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "before",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Value",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "connect.default": 0
              },
              "default": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "createdAt",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "connect.version": 1,
                  "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.ZonedTimestamp"
                }
              ],
              "default": null
            },
           
          ],
          "connect.name": "test2.Value"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "after",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "Value"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
   
  ],
  "connect.name": "test2.Envelope"
}
```

I want to implement join between these two topics KStream and Ktable.

How to implement by using test1 topic id and test2 topic id(which is inside the after obj), how can I extract the id from an object (after obj by using envelope schema) for implenting join.

Answer (score 0):

### Left Join (KStream, KTable) → KStream

- It performs a LEFT JOIN of a stream with the table, effectively doing a table lookup.
- The input data for both sides must be co-partitioned.
- It causes data re-partitioning of the stream if and only if the stream was marked for re-partitioning

KStream<String, Long> left = ...;

KTable<String, Double> right = ...;

KStream<String, String> joined = left.leftJoin(right,
(leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue, /* ValueJoiner */

Joined.keySerde(Serdes.String()) /* key */ .withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()) /* left value */ );

### Detailed behaviour

- The join is key-based, i.e. with the join predicate leftRecord.key == rightRecord.key.
- The join will be triggered under the conditions listed below whenever new input is received. When it is triggered, the user-supplied ValueJoiner will be called to produce join output records.
- Only input records for the left side (stream) trigger the join. Input records for the right side (table) update only the internal right-side join state.
- Input records for the stream with a null key or a null value are ignored and do not trigger the join.
- Input records for the table with a null value are interpreted as tombstones for the corresponding key, which indicate the deletion of the key from the table. Tombstones do not trigger the join.
- For each input record on the left side that does not have any match on the right side, the ValueJoiner will be called with ValueJoiner#apply(leftRecord.value, null).

Very low level detailed implementation here https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/joins/

Also refer the session 2.7 in https://mydeveloperplanet.com/2019/10/30/kafka-streams-joins-explored/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm implementing the join in the same way but still got an issue, Because from test2 schema Id is not extracted. so that I'm not able to implement this join.

Can you please let be know the what is the right approach to extract id from the before object or after object.